# Fastest way to start android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am new to android development and was wondering what is the fastest way to use the android emulator?

My current process is as follows:

1. Start the android emulator by pressing the "Run app" button (green play button
2. App emulator takes about 2 minutes to load (I'm ok with it taking this long to load on start)
3. I make some code changes, and press the "Run app" button again and it takes about another minute or so to move my changes to the emulator.

Is this how long it generally takes? It seems like a long time to have to wait to test changes and can get annoying when trying to write code quickly.

I am currently running on Ubuntu 14.04 if that needs to be stated as well

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I'd experienced hell with 4GB of RAM. Tried both in windows and ubuntu. I even reformatted my Notebook to let android studio + emulator took up all my RAM. So what I can say is, You need at least 8GB of RAM for developing in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks choz, i'll move my development from my laptop to my desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Emulator snapshot](http://tools.android.com/recent/emulatorsnapshots) is your friend on initial bootup. Also, [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is much faster for development. For speeding up the native emulator, you can try some of these tricks [here](http://jolicode.com/blog/speed-up-your-android-emulator)

Comment: My work will most likely not spring the bill for Genymotion...Any other solutions?

Comment: Thanks Derek, i'll check out the free version and come back and confirm the answer once I've verified it works for me